# the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors warning

Tags: php, mysql

So I think I'll never get an answer lol ...

**Old Question, please read the EDIT**

I am trying to display a picture after uploading it to a mysql database.

But by trying to open the picture firefox shows the following warning:

> the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

I already had been searching google because of it for hours now but I really can't find a fix for this issue. So now you guys are my very last hope :)

Here is the php:

```
    <?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db('...',$con);

$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT image, mime FROM artikel WHERE id='$id'");

$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
header("Content-type: $row->mime");
echo $row->image;
    ?>
```

**EDIT**
I think the mistake is in the insert.php..
Could someone please have a look at it and tell mewhat might be wrong? Thank you :) (I think the image is not uploaded correct)

```
<?php
session_start();
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$typ = $_POST['typ'];
$titel = $_POST['titel'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$timestamp = time();

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "...", "...", "...");
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die("Unable to connect to database: " . $db->connect_error);
}

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Verweis auf Bild
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        // Vorbereiten für den Upload in DB
        $data = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        // Metadaten auslesen
        $meta = getimagesize($image);
        $mime = $meta['mime'];
}

//create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->set_charset("utf8");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO artikel (`red`, `typ`, `titel`, `content`, `image`, `mime`, `timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

//bind the username and message
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $uname, $typ, $titel, $content, $data, $mime, $timestamp);

//run the query to insert the row
$stmt->execute();

header("Location: erfolg.php");

?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did u try to set the `header` in comment? This way u will see any warnings/errors the script is throwing. Be sure no warnings and errors are present before forcing the script as image

Comment: Are you sure the table from which you fetch the image is called `artikel`?

Comment: @l0lander Yes I am :) It is the german meaning of article.

Comment: use print_r($row) to confirm whether you are retrieving the image. To display an image you need to point the location. Just name will display only the name.

Comment: oh, then i learned something already :)

Comment: @DarkBee It doesn't show any warnings :/ This is what it shows after changing the header: http://t1p.de/babz

Comment: @Alaksandar Jesus Gene using print_r($row) doesn't help. Still no image but this: http://t1p.de/babz

Comment: echo '<img src="'.$row->image.'" />'; Try this.

Comment: @Alaksandar Jesus Gene It still doesn't work :( Why is this not working?

Comment: I shall work it out and keep you posted

Comment: @Alaksandar Jesus Gene Ok thanks :) Do you need a screenshot of the mysql table configuration or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction from [here](https://vikasmahajan.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/inserting-and-displaying-images-in-mysql-using-php/). I inserted the image with additional mime field and checked the code is working.

Confirm whether you have your mime types correct. If yes, then possibly the image might be corrupted.

having simply

```
header("Content-type: ");
```

also worked for me.[image: ScreenShot of my table][image: Screenshot of the data]

```
$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);



 /*Only for testing purpose.*/
                //  echo $row->mime;    //This line should output image/jpeg
 /*Only for testing purpose*/


 /*Only to check output*/
        header("Content-type: $row->mime");

        echo $row->image;
 /*Only to check output*/
```

Comment: Here is my working files. You can download it and test in your local server.     http://iseedtechnologies.in/other/downloads/stackoverflowImageEnquiry.tar.gz

Comment: Hi there ... Now I think my loadpic.php is working fine - The mistake seems to be in the insert script. Could you please have a look at insert.php and tell me what could be wrong there? Thanks :) (I added insert.php to the question)

Comment: you are passing 7 parameters whereas in bind you have given 8 parameters. Your 5th param is image whereas you are passing $content to 5th param. Can you look into it whether you were right?

Comment: Check your syntax for bindparam here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I think I am already passing  $meta to 5th param.. With the bindparam should be everything ok isn't it? I'm not sure why all this doesn't work ... I already checked everything more than 10 times and I just can't find the mistake.. There is the mysql database, then there is the form, next step is the insert.php, and then the last step is loadpic.php. And I don't know where this stupid misatake is... It is annoying

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Check whether you are getting values inserted. If inserted and still getting error, post pics of database compared to my earlier post.

```
//create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->set_charset("utf8");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO artikel (`red`, `typ`, `titel`, `content`, `image`, `mime`, `timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

//run the query to insert the row
$stmt->execute(array($uname, $typ, $titel, $content, $data, $mime, $timestamp));

header("Location: erfolg.php");
```

Comment: Ok, have a look at the question, I added a screenshot of the database. btw is it right to insert $data for image? Or should I insert $meta or $image?

Comment: you are assigning $data to image contents. And so you need to insert $data only for image. And $meta is for image size and $image is just reference of name. From your last update i see the BLOB size only 5B. Whereas my output give you 5KiB. So its clear that you are not uploading the image contents. Please work on my latest code and update.

Comment: Ok I updated it. But image still can't be displayed.

Comment: Hey again.. I added a screenshot of my sql structure... maybe there is a mistake